running python rest server in mojo
Since python rest server would be running in mojo and not in cpython we could get multithreading and not be worried about gil is this assumption correct? if anyone tried this combination do share experience...
i would like to expose running a sentence transformer using rest interface will try that stuff in max and keep the rest interface in python may be using quart for async rest calls. The sentence transformer part could be written in mojo and the rest in python all running as one mojo executable

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
